# How can I convert a curl command into node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following curl command. Curl in bash works ok but when I write equivalent in node.js (any http library), it doesn't seem to work

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://www.delta.com/shop/modals/flightspecific' \
--header 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' \
--header 'cachekey: d6469dbe-b47e-4f46-be02-12b900011c7c' \
--header 'Accept-Encoding: compressed' \
--data-raw '{"legList":[{"originAirportCode":"BOS","destinationAirportCode":"JFK","schedLocalDepartDate":"2020-03-10T08:30","marketingAirlineCode":"DL","operatingAirlineCode":"9E","classOfServiceList":["NE","NV","SN","OZ"],"flightNumber":"5419"}],"pageId":"dynamic-modal","appId":"sho","channelId":"ecomm"}'
```

Which works fine (returns JSON). But this code does not work

```
const axios = require("axios");

headers = {
  "user-agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36",
  "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
  cachekey: "d6469dbe-b47e-4f46-be02-12b900011c7c",
  "Accept-Encoding": "compressed"
};

data =
  '{"legList":[{"originAirportCode":"BOS","destinationAirportCode":"JFK","schedLocalDepartDate":"2020-03-10T08:30","marketingAirlineCode":"DL","operatingAirlineCode":"9E","classOfServiceList":["NE","NV","SN","OZ"],"flightNumber":"5419"}],"pageId":"dynamic-modal","appId":"sho","channelId":"ecomm"}';

url = "https://www.delta.com/shop/modals/flightspecific";

options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: headers,
  data: data,
  url: url
};

axios(options).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: have you tried with `data` as the JS object rather than string? `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Yes, tried that, no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try something Like this  :

```
var Request = require("request");
 var headers = {
           "user-agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36",
  "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
  cachekey: "d6469dbe-b47e-4f46-be02-12b900011c7c",
  "Accept-Encoding": "compressed"
        };
data =
  '{"legList":[{"originAirportCode":"BOS","destinationAirportCode":"JFK","schedLocalDepartDate":"2020-03-10T08:30","marketingAirlineCode":"DL","operatingAirlineCode":"9E","classOfServiceList":["NE","NV","SN","OZ"],"flightNumber":"5419"}],"pageId":"dynamic-modal","appId":"sho","channelId":"ecomm"}';

        Request.post({
            "headers": headers,
            "url": "https://www.delta.com/shop/modals/flightspecific",
            "body": JSON.stringify(data )
        }, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                console.dir(error);
            }
            if (body) {
              console.dir(JSON.parse(body));
           }

        });
```